# How can I view source code for datetime.py from PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm ctrl-clicking on the `datetime.timedelta` function from within PyCharm, and getting to a file named ....PyCharm10\system\python_stubs\76178323\datetime.py, which appears to contain many empty methods. Specifically, ctrl-clicking on datetime.delta brings me to this part of the file:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        pass
```

Is this a bug? How can I view/trace through the real datetime.py?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, there is no way. Possible, OS does not contain source code of the library, only the compiled binary (e.g. /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so).

Comment: Since 2003, datetime was written in C, so no pure Python source code would be the default I guess. Python 3.2 has a datetime module in pure Python again.